# How can I customize $PROMPT_COMMAND without overwriting the default (if present)?

Tags: bash, shell, bashrc, rc

Mac's Terminal comes with a default `PROMPT_COMMAND` that checks the history and updates the current working directory (title of the tab):

Add `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` to the top of your `.bash_profile` and you'll see:

```
shell_session_history_check; update_terminal_cwd
```

---

I want to add my own `PROMPT_COMMAND` without over-writing the default. The default should come before my custom `PROMPT_COMMAND` with a semicolon and space to separate the two.

Note that some programs (such as IntelliJ and VS Code) don't have a default! So I wouldn't want to include the space/semicolon in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# If PC contains anything, add semicolon and space
if [ ! -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
    PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND; "
fi

# Add custom PC
PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND'CUSTOM_PC_HERE'
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Bash 5.1, `PROMPT_COMMAND` can be an array; you can add your own command as the first one to be executed with

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND=(mycommand "${PROMPT_COMMAND[@]}")
```

This also works if the existing value of `PROMPT_COMMAND` contains multiple commands in a single string.

---

For older Bash, such as the stock macOS bash, you can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) with `:+` for this:

> `${parameter:+word}`
> If *`parameter`* is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of *`word`* is substituted.

An example:

```
$ unset var
$ var=${var:+"$var; "}XXX
$ echo "$var"
XXX
$ var=abc
$ var=${var:+"$var; "}XXX
$ echo "$var"
abc; XXX
```

So to keep the existing command with `;`  appended, I use

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND:+"$PROMPT_COMMAND; "}'mycommand'
```

If `PROMPT_COMMAND` is empty before, it contains just `mycommand` afterwards, and if it wasn't, `;`  is inserted between the existing command and `mycommand`.